# Whole Number Groups

Tags: code-golf, number, rational-numbers

Given a list of fractions, group them so that each group sums to a whole number. This should be done in such a way to maximize the number of non-empty groups.

You may assume a solution exists. Order does not matter, both for the groups and their contents. You may output in any order.

### Test Cases

| Fractions | Groups |
| --- | --- |
| `1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2` | `(1/2, 1/2), (1/2, 1/2)` |
| `1/2, 1/3, 1/6, 6/7, 8/7` | `(1/2, 1/3, 1/6), (8/7, 6/7)` |
| `5/3, 2/3, 2/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3` | `(1/3, 5/3), (1/3, 2/3), (1/3, 2/3)` |
| `9/2, 3/4, 1/12, 7/4, 2/3, 2/3, 7/12` | `(9/2, 3/4, 1/12, 2/3), (7/4, 2/3, 7/12)` |
| `1/10, 1/5, 1/2, 7/10, 1/2` | `(1/10, 1/5, 7/10), (1/2, 1/2)` |

### IO

You may take fractions as a tuple or list of `[numerator, denominator]`, and output in the same format. You can also use your language's built-in fraction type if it exists.

If there are multiple optimal solutions you may output any of them, some of them, or all of them. Do not output any non-optimal solutions.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25584/91213)

Comment: Because of floating point errors I think this test case can be also added: `1/10, 1/5, 1/2, 7/10, 1/2` -> `(1/10, 1/5, 7/10), (1/2, 1/2)`

Comment: Can we take two lists, one of numerators and one of denominators?

Comment: @CommandMaster I can't really imagine why that would be helpful but sure. Looking forward to see what kind of loophole you find with that format.

Comment: Can I output the modified fractions? For example instead of `1/2` output the `2/4`

Comment: @EzioMercel No.

Comment: Just as a clarification for everyone: the 4th test case has 3 valid solutions: `(1/12, 2/3, 2/3, 7/12), (3/4, 7/4, 9/2)`, `(1/12, 2/3, 3/4, 9/2), (2/3, 7/12, 7/4)` and `(1/12, 2/3, 7/4, 9/2), (2/3, 3/4, 7/12)`.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 176 bytes

Expects a list of `[numerator, denominator]` pairs.

```javascript
a=>eval("for(o=n=a.length,q=n**n;q--;)o[(p=a.map((_,j)=>a.filter((_,i)=>!(q/n**i%n^j))).filter(a=>a+a)).length]||p.some(b=>b.map(([p,q])=>[P=P*q+p*Q,Q*=q],P=0,Q=1)|P%Q)?o:o=p")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVHRboIwFH3fVzATkxYLpSBUZ@p@AZ4JW6oDh8G2qPHJf2etjU6UZX3ouefe5pyc3i0/8cN6X6ujJ@RX2VWs42xZnngDRpXcA8kE435Tis3xG7VMuK5YtJ63gDIHSk92XAHwibaQLblf1c2x3Btea/4KWqzf12PxsYUQXqdank@45la0OJ@Vf5C7EqzYcmX1coXaQivkKUvddqLcDGUuawuUsgBljMBzOs7gu3yTTI1gt5biIJvSb@QGVCDPCQoL5AyAM3wKCB2MHUBwiBx9QXRXv/ypHllIDCSIGphp@Ec9MldiLGaYIifB9NkittphD8gTDFho9RhHNoCuw4f6yWluw0RoakXJhVJL@/7UDK9OcxMmwlMThoQ3I2o6oXGjuj30dySwRvHdauit@7ii32AkMFbxRTjoLaj7AQ)

#### Commented

This is a version without `eval()` for readability.

```javascript
a => {                     // a[] = input list of fractions
  for(                     // main loop:
    o =                    //   o[] = output, initially not an array
    n = a.length,          //   n = length of a[]
    q = n ** n;            //   q = counter, initialized to n ** n
    q--;                   //   stop once q = 0 has been processed
  )                        //
  o[                       // test o[], using the length of p[]:
    ( p =                  //   p[] = partition
      a.map((_, j) =>      //   for each element at index j in a[]:
        a.filter((_, i) => //     for each element at index i in a[]:
          !(               //       keep this entry if
            q / n ** i % n //       floor(q / n ** i) mod n
            ^ j            //       is equal to j
          )                //
        )                  //     end of filter()
      ).filter(a => a + a) //   end of map(); remove empty slots
    ).length               //   get the final length of p[]
  ] ||                     // abort if p[] is longer than o[]
  p.some(b =>              // for each list of fractions b[] in p[]:
    b.map(([p, q]) =>      //   for each fraction [p, q] in b[]:
      [                    //     we add p/q to P/Q by:
        P = P * q + p * Q, //       updating the numerator P
        Q *= q             //       updating the denominator Q
      ],                   //
      P = 0, Q = 1         //     start with P/Q = 0/1
    )                      //   end of map()
    | P % Q                //   trigger some() if Q is not a divisor of P
  ) ? 0                    // end of some(); do nothing if truthy
    : o = p;               // otherwise, update o[] to p[]
                           // (implicit end of for)
  return o                 // return o[]
}                          //
```

Comment: So the `eval` is just a way to avoid the braces and the `return`?

Comment: @Jonah Yes. It saves 3 bytes here because `o` is the last thing that gets evaluated by the one liner. Otherwise, we'd have to end it with an extra `;o` and it would save only one byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
ṖvøṖÞf'Ṡ¨=⌊;ÞG
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhIiwiIiwi4bmWdsO44bmWw55mJ+G5oMKoPeKMijvDnkciLCIiLCIxLzJcbjEvM1xuMS82XG42LzdcbjgvNyJd)

Times out for anything more than 5 fractions if you're lucky. Don't even bother giving it the third and fourth test case.

Inputs as a list of fraction objects. Due to technical limitations, this is done with the `a` flag for convenience.

### Explained

```
ṖvøṖÞf'Ṡ¨=⌊;ÞG # We'll call the length of the list N so we can see why this takes so long
Ṗ              # Permutations of the input - returns a list of N! items
 vøṖ           # To each of the N! permutations, get all possible partitions. Each permutation has 2^(N-1) partitions, so there are now N! * 2^(N-1) sublists but still N! items
    Þf         # Flatten the entire thing by one level. This iterates over each of those N! * 2^(N-1) sublists.
      '    ;   # From those partitions of permutations, keep only those where: (also iterating over each of those N! * 2^(N-1) items)
       Ṡ       #   Summating each partition
        ¨=⌊    #   is invariant under flooring
            ÞG # Get the longest remaining item.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 148 bytes

```
Last@Sort@(y=Flatten)[(a=#;(x=Select)[a~TakeList~#&/@x[Range@n~Tuples~#&~Array~(n=Length@a)~y~1,Tr@#==n&],Tr@Mod[Tr/@#,1]==0&])&/@Permutations@#,1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoJAFEXXfceAKAhm0SoeTJtWBpLuBhcPe6ikY8w8QYnm1yeLoMWByz1wuQNySwNyV6NvwGdoWRajYRkucO6RmXSkQgRxDGcoqKeaI4WuxDtlnWUngkTO6oq6IaldOT16smvpTsbg4kINGemGW4mRW1wal0YKAB1Un3QZb6o0iRRxWgFsgypax3Iyw8TroVHbrwl8bjrNslHPQ7KPdz/SP69q4/0b)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>24</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œ€.œ€`éʒε.EOT.òDïQ}P}θ
```

-2 bytes by taking the input as a list of strings `"a/b"` instead of list of pairs `[a,b]`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORHTWv0wGTC4ZWnJp3bqufqH6J3eJPL4fWBtQG153b8/x@tZKhvpKSjZKFvDiQN9Y3BpBmQNAOKxAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o5MfNa3RA5MJh1eemnRuq56rf4je4U0uh9cH1gbUntvxX@d/dLSSob6Rkg4GGaujgJAyBpNmQNJM3xxIWgBJsAJTsJQREmmIRkLNMTQA803hdpjDhKBWWYJFjfVNwIKGECUmaIabgyRiYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
œ            # Get all permutations of the (implicit) input-list
 €.œ         # Get all partitions of each permutation
    €`       # Flatten it one level down to a single list of partitions
      é      # Sort it by length (shortest to longest)
ʒ            # Filter this list of partitions by:
 ε           #  Map over each part of this partition:
  .E         #   Evaluate each inner string as Elixir to get the decimals
    O        #   Sum them together
     T.ò     #   Round it to 10 decimal values to fix floating point errors
        DïQ  #   Check that it's an integer:
        D    #    Duplicate
         ï   #    Cast the copy to an integer (floor for positive integers)
          Q  #    Check if the two are equal
 }P          #  After the map: check if all parts in this partition were truthy
}θ           # After the filter: pop and leave the last/longest valid partition
             # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 92 bytes

```
≔Ｅ⪪Ｓ,⁺⟦ικ⟧Ｉ⪪ι/θ≔ΠＥθ§ι³ηＦθ⊞ι×÷η⊟ι⊟ιＷθ«≔ΦＥＸ²ＬθΦθ﹪÷κＸ²ν²∧κ¬﹪ΣＥκ§μ²ηι≔§ι⌕ＥιＬκ⌊ＥιＬκι≔⁻θιθ⟦⪫Ｅι§κ⁰,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHda4MwEH9u/4rgU4QMVx2UsSfZKHTMIbi30gdRZw5j4kdsB2N/u7ukceuYEDnufl@XFDwfCpWLeY7HEWpJk7yjWSdA073sJp3pAWRNfUY85uE/FdNID8BIc2TkMR@1A2PHCzwfP0Z6/2Ht1NJBlVOhrWrPSKz3sqw@DDqyUI7QdzUQ2vsknUZuJm/QViO66yc4QVlRjq6qo2DwrkDWmYOoLO9zvXJuOxC6GqxZqs5YhYy8VLLWHHHIdnMMkmAsoa5MGqPtKNJgQ5svlqUZvSpc4ULJptYaNL/btAuaX/YHjLdEutp4ByhmqPCTqjHwBCS0TvXP6J8YIvH2e9O83PIqxdfR9PCsQC78xRED3vru3Y6I/Zrn@yBkUXDHNsEmZFsswiCyZ4uN@eYkvgE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ⪪Ｓ,⁺⟦ικ⟧Ｉ⪪ι/θ
```

Input the fractions and split them into numerator and denominator.

```
≔ΠＥθ§ι³η
```

Calculate a common denominator that will work for all of the fractions.

```
Ｆθ⊞ι×÷η⊟ι⊟ι
```

Calculate the equivalent numerator for each fraction.

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until there are no more fractions to process.

```
≔ΦＥＸ²ＬθΦθ﹪÷κＸ²ν²∧κ¬﹪ΣＥκ§μ²ηι
```

Get all of the subsets of the fractions but filter out the empty set and any set whose sum of numerators isn't a multiple of the common denominator.

```
≔§ι⌕ＥιＬκ⌊ＥιＬκι
```

Find the shortest such subset.

```
≔⁻θιθ
```

Remove the shortest subset from the remaining fractions.

```
⟦⪫Ｅι§κ⁰,
```

Output the original fractions from the shortest subset.